# How do I make Windows 10 only show me the windows associated with the CURRENT virtual desktop when I hover an app's taskbar icon?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have 5 or 6 virtual desktops in Windows 10, both on my home PC and my work desktop. At work, I'm able to have e.g. a separate instance of Sublime Text open on every virtual desktop, and on any given desktop when I hover over the taskbar icon, it will only show me the windows that are open on the current virtual desktop.

However, on my home laptop (which I keep updated, unlike the work PC which is strictly managed by IT), I see EVERY window from EVERY desktop when I hover the taskbar icon, no matter which desktop I'm on.

I'm fairly sure this is a Windows setting and not an app-specific setting because it happens for both Chrome and Sublime Text.

How can I change this behavior back to the way it used to be? Is there a particular Windows update that I need to roll back?

Answer (score 0):

Hit task view---> right click the window of the desired app or file---> deselect "**show this window on all desktops**" and  "**show windows from this app on all desktops**". After that you have to drag and drop every opened file to different desktop.

Comment: That does something different, it just prevents the app windows themselves from appearing on all desktops, but it does nothing to prevent all the app previews from appearing when you hover the over the app's taskbar icon.

Answer (score -1):

In Windows 11 its at:
System > Multitasking > Desktops > First Entry

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).